# Z-index property does not work

Tags: html, css, z-index

here is what i have done:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/51/)

the `<li id="L1">` is from `class` `active` so it has a `border-bottom` in color white, so i suppose to cover the black border of the div and look like under that `<li>` there is no border- it dosent do that

the div has the property `z-index:-1` and it's `position` is `relative`.

why isn't it over? and how do i fix it? 
Thanks for the help

if you dont mind, update the fiddle with your answer

html:

```
    <div id='settingNev' style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
<ul style="left:200px; z-index:1px;">
  <li id="L1" class="active" runat="server"><a id="A1" href="../newsFeed/allEr.aspx" runat="server"><span>Er</span></a></li>
   <li id="L2" runat="server"><a id="A2" href="../newsFeed/allEe.aspx" runat="server"><span>Ee</span></a></li>
   <li id="L3" runat="server"><a id="A3" href="#" runat="server"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li id="L4" runat="server"><a id="A4" href="#" runat="server"><span>2</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div style="border-top:1px solid ; position:relative; top:-11px; background-color:white; width:130%; height:60%; z-index:-1"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#settingNev
{
}
#settingNev ul {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
#settingNev ul li {
    display:inline;
    background-color:transparent;
}
#settingNev ul li a {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 6px 3px 6px 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px 0 1px 1px;
}

#settingNev .active a
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    background-color:White;
}
#settingNev ul li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 6px 3px 6px 4px;
}
#settingNev .active a:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
}
```

Comment: FYI `<ul style="left:200px; z-index:1px;">` `1px` isn't valid.

Comment: Actually, the div is below the menu. The height you've set in % isn't working so it has 0 height. http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2fDQz/45/

You need to first position them on top of each other.

Comment: changed it to 1 and it's still doesnt work

Comment: As per [this website's posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you must also post the code within the OP _in addition_ to any jsFiddle.

Comment: @TilwinJoy does it suppose to matter? i just want the the div's border will be unders the menu

Comment: added the code to the OP

Comment: @Cooper as far as i can see in the fiddle i shared, the divs border is under the menu. By under, if you meant to  hide it, like i said you need to position them on top of each other.
Please avoid using inline styles, it's easy for you to write, but makes it hard to read and work with the code for others.

Comment: i dont think it's under, the <li> L1 is from class active so it has a border-bottom in color white, so it suppose to cover the black border of the div and look like under that li there is no border- it dosent do that. sorry i didnt write that in the main post, i added it right now

Comment: **Like i said twice unless you position them on top of each other, the border of the div will be rendered below the content above it, so it won't be hidden!**

Comment: @TilwinJoy alright i get it, i thought that z-index fixes it. Thanks for the help i will change it, if you want to write an answer for further notice i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dont understand if your problem here is why you see the black line across the page. In this case be cafeful because the menu and the black line are not overlapping.

Another thing here I want to point is that your li elements have background-color:transparent; so even if the menu has more z-index, you will see the black line when they overlap with your elements. You will see the difference if you set background color to white and check it out.

As I mentioned, the elements are not overlapping, do this and you will have the selected tab with no black line at the bottom. Now they overlap and you dont see the black line and everything works well.

```
#settingNev .active a {
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Just in case z-index: 1px is not valid, it should be z-index: 1

Comment: already changed the z-index to 1, didnt help. i have tried chenging the background color to white- also didnt do any change:http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/51/

Comment: Please explain me what do you want to acomplish so I can help you better. I saw that the black line does not overlapp with your menu so it is all OK in your example. Everything is working as it is defined.

Comment: I answered, check the update, you needed more padding for the elements to overlap

Comment: well i didnt think of that, i wanted the borders to overlap. this works too! Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Note: Updated answer below.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/49/

Changes:

As mentioned, `z-index:1px;` is not valid.

removed `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` from `<a>`

The a:hover should have a z-index greater than the others (set to 2) and a white background (transparent is default)

Comment: i want that only the <a> from class active will look like it has no border under it, so only to that has border-bottom white